# OAuth not granting access while using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, oauth-2.0, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to call StackExchange's API, using Google Apps Script and Google Sheets. I can't figure out where in the OAuth process things are going wrong. My current code is not granting access:

```
function getStackExchangeService_() {
  var CLIENT_ID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('SE_CLIENT_ID');
  var CLIENT_SECRET = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('SE_CLIENT_SECRET');

  return OAuth2.createService('StackExchange')
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://stackoverflow.com/oauth')
  .setTokenUrl('https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token')
  .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
  .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
  .setRedirectUri('https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success')
  .setScope('global');
}
```

When I call this and log the response I always get "false":

```
var service = getStackExchangeService_();
Logger.log(service.hasAccess());
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's not quite a proper [mcve]. And, for example, are you using [this library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2)?

Comment: You should also configure the code to relay any (error) messages from the Stack Exchange server and report them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious issue is that **`global` is not [a valid Stack Exchange scope](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication#scope).**

Probably use `.setScope('read_inbox');` to start.

Also, be sure that:

1. You have [registered your app and configured it for explicit (server-side) OAuth2](https://stackapps.com/questions/4596/can-the-redirect-uri-contain-port-number/7852#7852). (Omit the port information in your case.)
2. Apparently you should use `https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback` for the `Application Website`, per [these instructions](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#user-content-redirect-uri)??.
3. Which means you would use `script.google.com` for the `OAuth Domain`.

Comment: Thanks @brock, this is helpful and I think am on the right track. `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id={ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback&scope=read_inbox` gets me the code, though `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={ID}&client_secret={SECRET}&code={CODE}&redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback` takes me to a "Page not found" on Stackoverflow. Any idea where I am still going wrong?

Comment: @poyter16, it may be that you did not `POST` to stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token.  Also, the `redirect_uri` may be invalid. But we'd need you to provide a proper [mcve] to be sure.  Anyway, [mark this Q&A as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and ask a new question, with that MCVE, for the new error.